# How to select from SQL table so even and odd rows would be in separate columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

There is a table ID in my PostgreSQL database.

```
select * from ID;

ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I need to write a query that will give me this output:

```
id id 
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such things as *even* and *odd* rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (well technically multi-sets).

Assuming `id` is the ordering, you can split them using aggregation like this:

```
select min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 2)
```